# Site redirect with nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I tried doing some site redirection with nginx, but even after reading some documentation and trying a few things, it doesn't seem to work.

in my nginx.conf file, I added a section.

```
server {
    server_name whatever.domain.org/sub_site;
    return 301 $scheme://Some.other.domaine2.com$request_uri;
}
```

It seemed pretty basic, but when I try going to "whatever.domain.org/sub_site" in a browser, the url does not seem to exist... The url that is supposed to be returned works in a browser directly though.

"whatever.domain.org" is the adress of my nginx server, and I want to be able to redirect to a different address for each different "sub_site" entered in the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server_name` argument must contain *only* a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) and cannot have URL components.

If you need to scope this redirect to a particular section of the site, try using the [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) directive:

```
rewrite ^/sub_site(.*)$ $scheme://Some.other.domaine2.com$1 redirect;
```

Comment: Just tried that, removed the sub_site from the server_name, but I still have an error when entering the sub_site url in a browser. Do I need to add things in other files, like add something in sites-available or sitres-enabled?

Comment: What error do you have? That would help considerably in diagnosing this.

Comment: Well, I had the error in French, but it said somethign like "this page does not exist, please check that the address is correct". I wanted to give you the exact message in english, so I opened another browser, but the redirection worked in that one... Seems it does not work in IE...

Comment: That is odd. I'd make a point of testing with `curl` first, it gives you some low-level diagnostics with things like `-i`, and various versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: In the end, it was because of a proxy setting in IE. Working now.

Comment: Had to change it for a proxy_pass since we wanted to keep the url, and not the redirected url, but encountered some issues. I created another question since it's a new problem.